# Use of a predictor variable for a dependent variable that is directly related to the predictor variable

Tags: regression, logistic, predictor, independence

If I would like to predict a binary variable `x`, and `x` is true if `y` is true and `z` is not true, can I use `y` as a predictor variable? So, in essence, I would assert that `y` evaluating to true is already a pretty good predictor for `x`. I have the sense that this is methodologically difficult, though.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem here. Can you put some flesh on these bones? What is the real situation you face & what are your ultimate goals? (Note that your description is consistent with a situation where `y` in isolation is useless as a predictor of `x`.)

Comment: I would like to predict unauthorized trading of a stock, `x`, which is present if someone trades that stock, `y`, without disclosing it, `z`. Just trading that stock is already a pretty good predictor for unauthorized trading.